# Showing file name in Jekyll with Pygments code highlight

Tags: jekyll, pygments

When highlighting a standard file at a known location I'd like to put the file name in the code block; preferably at the top. A hypothetical example would be

```
{% highlight apache show_filename=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf %}
.... the file contents ....
{% endhighlight %}
```

which would then render a code block with a filename prefixed. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, that is not part of what pygments offers. You could simply add a block directly above the code block and highlight that as plain text.

Comment: I presume it could be done with a plugin. I don't know enough Ruby to write one, though.

Comment: This potential jekyll-feature [has been discussed on github](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5020), also by the name `caption` for the filename. – However, as far as I can see, there is no fancy attribute to add out of the box. (Not in pygments, not in rouge, no relevant mentions of kramdown...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the nice html5 **figure** tag.

> > "*The HTML  Element represents self-contained content, frequently with a caption (figcaption), and is typically referenced as a single unit. While it is related to the main flow, its position is independent of the main flow. Usually this is an image, an illustration, a diagram, a code snippet, or a schema that is referenced in the main text, but that can be moved to another page or to an appendix without affecting the main flow.*" 
> >     [MDN > html > figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>File: folderName/fileName.rb</figcaption>
  {% highlight ruby %}
  def print_hi(name)
    puts "Hi, #{name}"
  end
  {% endhighlight %}
</figure>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just because of how much time has passed, but for me the highlight template tag also creates its own figure tag when rendering, so I end up with a figure inside a figure with this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Another, a bit nicer solution which will work with **kramdown**:

```
>Some/test/xml/file.xml
{:.filename}
{% highlight xml %}
.... the file content ....
{% endhighlight %}
```

And in you .css file you can make it look nice with your code snippet, for example like this:

```
.fileName{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #292929;
  color: lightgrey;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-family: Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
  border-left: 0px;    
}
```

[Here](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes) you can find more info about this kramdown feature.