# Show extra info of code snippet in jekyll pygments

Tags: jekyll, highlight, pygments

Jekyll, pygments, I want to show the detail info about some code snippet: file name, related links, just as this:

```
{% highlight [language] [linenos] ["title"] [links] %}
.... code snippet ....
{% endhighlight %}
```

How can I achieve this? The ruby script is the last thing I want to do, for GitHub do not support it?

Comment: You can add those details outside the highlighted code block, [using the HTML element `<figure>` for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881134/showing-file-name-in-jekyll-with-pygments-code-highlight).

Comment: No native support till now? When I try the solution from the link you give, the style is not the same as the code snippet displayed: the color, and extra indent... Also, please edit the answer below, let me close this, thanks!

Comment: I also tried octopress before, and it achieved this feature, is there any magic?

Comment: You were probably using the plugin [Codeblock](http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/codeblock/). I don't know if we can do the same with pygments, docs are scarce. I'm not sure which answer you're referring to.